# Using LDAP for storing business data rather than organizational data only

Tags: java, architecture, active-directory, ldap, rdbms

The business domain of a solution contains the following objects:

- users
- resources (strings representing ids of real-world objects like products)
- groups of users
- groups of resources
- rights granted to users to act upon resources in a certain way

I need to evaluate whether the solution shall use a relational database or if we can do everything in LDAP with a custom schema.

The proposed solution so far uses some UI framework for the front-end and a REST API to connect to the backend. The business objects on the back end are realized as EJBs. The EJBs use only LDAP with a custom schema (option 1) or a "standard" LDAP and a RDBMS (option 2) for persistance.

I have no experience with custom LDAP schemas and I feel uncomfortable to persist data that is not related to organization (like people, equipment, etc.) but to it's business (like products etc.) to LDAP. On the other hand I do not see any reason why this is not such a good idea.

Here are some of the key requirements:

- web front-end
- users and user groups are managed in LDAP
- possibility for the future to extend the solution in such a way that the resources contain not only ids of real-world objects but also have BLOBs associated with them
- writes to the database are far less frequent than reads
- no transactions are required
- on-premise solution that can easily be integrated into various IT environment